# Php - Remove backslash from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, stripslashes

I'm using a 3rd party CMS system and am creating a page that has a designated print layout but when I'm returning the data I'm getting unwanted backslashes. IE. `\"Scrutiny Process\"` rather than `"Scrutiny Process"`. I'm aware of the strip slashes function but how would I use it in the following?

```
if ($title = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
do {printf("%s", $title["page_content"]);}
  while ($title = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just put `stripslashes` everywhere where you extract strings from the rows, what's the problem?

Comment: is the date in `$title["page_content"]` to be modified?

Comment: `printf( "%s", stripslashes ($title["page_content"]) )`

Comment: That's got to be the weirdest `mysql_fetch_*` loop I've ever seen...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 stripcslashes($title["page_content"]);
```